# How to reduce the decimal places in a bar chart created by Plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-express

I need to reduce the decimal places to 2 in my bar chart created by Plotly Express.

[image: image of bar chart]

My code is:

```
 fig8 = px.bar(
    new_data,
    x=["Loyal", "Exited"],
    y=["active", "inactive"],
    title="Distribution of active membership in loyal and exited clients group",
    width=700,        
    orientation="v",
    color_discrete_map={"active": "green", "inactive": "yellow"},
    barmode="stack"
)
fig8.update_layout(xaxis_title_text="Types of clients", yaxis_title_text="Number of clients, %", barnorm="percent")
fig8.update_traces(marker_line_width = 0, texttemplate = "%{y}%")
fig8.layout["legend"]["title"] = "Type of clients' membership"
fig8.show()
```

For my bar chart, I've used this table where the data is not in percentages. I've chosen the `barnorm="percent"` and I can't change it to 2 decimal places.

[image]

I have tried different suggestions, such as setting `text_auto="%.2f"` and `texttemplate = "%{y:%.2f}%"`. It didn't help.

Comment: Please don’t spam tags which are irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to limit the number of decimals to 2 places after the decimal point:

```
fig8.update_traces(
    marker_line_width = 0, 
    texttemplate = "%{value:.2f}%"
)
```

Here is the full code and resulting bar chart:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

new_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "IsActiveMember": ['Exited','Loyal'],
    "active": [735, 4416],
    "inactive": [1302, 3547],
})
new_data = new_data.set_index("IsActiveMember")

fig8 = px.bar( 
    new_data, 
    x=["Loyal", "Exited"], 
    y=["active", "inactive"], 
    title="Distribution of active membership in loyal and exited clients group", 
    width=700,         
    orientation="v", 
    color_discrete_map={"active": "green", "inactive": "yellow"}, 
    barmode="stack" 
) 
fig8.update_layout(
    xaxis_title_text="Types of clients", 
    yaxis_title_text="Number of clients, %", 
    barnorm="percent"
) 

fig8.update_traces(
    marker_line_width = 0, 
    texttemplate = "%{value:.2f}%"
) 

fig8.layout["legend"]["title"] = "Type of clients' membership" 

fig8.show()
```

[image]